# How to compare start date and end date in java script side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In the javascript side, I am checking enddatetime >= startdatetime,but it's not working. How to handle it in Javascript side?

```
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="startTime" label="Start Time" class="field" value="{!v.startDateTimeVal}" displayDatePicker="true" required="true" />
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="endTime" label="End Time" class="field" value="{!v.endDateTimeVal}" displayDatePicker="true" required="true" />
```

---

Javascript side:

```
var stardateTime=component.find("startTime").get("v.value");
var enddateTime=component.find("endTime").get("v.value");
if(enddateTime>=stardateTime){
    component.set("v.truthy",true);
    component.set("v.message1", "End date Time cannot be a blank");
    return null;
}
```

Please check below image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to convert those values to Date values first:

```
if(new Date(enddateTime) >= new Date(stardateTime)) {
```

Comment: @AnnappaPH It's working as you wrote it; you might have meant `<=` instead?